# cannot perform this operation on a open/closed dataset?

Tags: delphi, ms-access, datamodule

Hi guys i've written a function which has to check the ID given to the function as `iID` and then output the name of the member of it is found, otherwise it must output that it is not found

A different table is active when this function is called so it must change the table to `Members` (to search the ID) and then back again afterwards (I have multiple tables)

```
function fCheckID(iID:integer):String;
var sTable:string;
begin
sTable:=datamoduleX.tableX.TableName;
datamoduleX.tableX.TableName:='Members';
 if datamoduleX.tableX.Locate('RefNo',iID,[]) then
  result:=dmRooiX.tblRooiX['Name']+' '+datamoduleX.tableX['Surname']
  else
  result:='ID: '+inttostr(iID)+' does not exist';
datamoduleX.tableX.TableName:=sTable;
end;
```

but the problem is every time I call this function I get an error that says "Cannot perform this operation on an open dataset"

if I close the dataset before I run the function I get "Cannot perform this operation on a closed dataset"

I know the error occurs when I try to access the table name or change it (the function does not give the error when those 3 lines are commented out)

I have no idea how to make this work
any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Use a prepared Query for that kind of operations

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know what you mean by that

Comment: Your approach is completely wrong, imo: a) you seem unaware that you can have more than one table open at the same time; b) Don't change a table's TableName to access a different table in the database, use a separate Table component instead; c) You do a Locate on a dataset in one datamodule but then look data up from another table in a different datamodule.  I think it would be best if you study a basic online Delphi db tutorial and start again.

Comment: Close; Change Table name; Open. <- This is a very poor solution though .I would use a local query (via `TADOQuery`) for this task (e.g `select * from Members where RefNo=:iID)`, instead of abusing `datamoduleX.tableX` which returns **all** records each time.

Comment: @MartynA thanks for the help. I'm only still in high school so this is all new to me. I will try adding multiple tables

Comment: No worries and good luck.  See my comment on the answer you've just accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example :

```
  Table1.TableName := 'TABLE1';
  Table1.Open;  
  Table1.TableName := 'TABLE2';  <-- Cannot perform this operation on Open data set. Because Table1 is open
  Table1.Locate('ID',11,[]);
```

simple solution

```
 Table1.TableName := 'TABLE1';
 Table1.Open;
 Table1.Close; <--Close table before change table name
 Table1.TableName := 'TABLE2';
 Table1.Open;  <-- Open new table before do Locate
 Table1.Locate('ID',11,[]);
```

Comment: Sorry, I think that for a beginner like the OP, using the same dataset component to access different datasets is only going to invite confusion and misunderstanding.  Why not just use another TDataSet?  I assume "IBTable1" is a typo?

Comment: @MartynA I agree with you. I now have different table components with their own dat as ounces

Comment: @MartynA Totally true. But this is just an example of where they come from error messages.